# How do I add a number to all "h2 tag"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Wordrpess site. I want add a number all to "h2 tag" for my all posts

The format of my posts:

```
text

<h2>text</h2>

text

<h2>text</h2>

text

<h2>text</h2>
...
...
```

I want this:

```
text

<h2>NUMBER-1 text</h2>

text

<h2>NUMBER-2 text</h2>

text

<h2>NUMBER-3 text</h2>
...
...
```

Comment: Is this in a loop? Do you want to do it via PHP? JavaScript?

Comment: Thank you. via functions.php

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to use the WordPress post content filter.

The filter can be called by:

```
function my_the_content_filter($content) {
  // do what you want to the content
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

Although using Regex for manipulating HTML is not great, here it is a simple enough case where you could use preg_match to find all of the  tags and then insert a number after them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for...

In the below code I am using a `for` loop to execute the code in the curly brackets a set amount of times. The first `$x` initialises the loop counter value, `$x <= $number_of_items;` sets the number of times to run the block and `$x++` increments the initial `$x`. I then insert the `$x` value into the code.

For more on PHP for loops please visit - https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

```
$number_of_items = 5;

for ($x = 0; $x <= $number_of_items; $x++) {
    echo "<h2>NUMBER-" . $x . " text</h2>";
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation with your code so OP can understand how it works. thanks

Comment: Thanks, explanation added.